# I can't understand why it has error LNK2019 "unresolvant external symbols"

Tags: visual-c++, dll, linker, static-libraries, glpk

I follow the insturction to compile glpk on windows, then I got glpk_4_52.lib and glpk_4_52.dll. In my VC 2010 project, I include head file

#include "glpk.h"

and I include glpk_4_52.lib in "additional library directory".

But after compiling it still shows:

error LNK2019, "unresolvant external symbols", _glp_create_prob, referenced in _main
and similar others.

Could anyone knows what the problem is here? Thanks!d

Comment: From where did you get source and build instruction for "glpk_4_52"?

Comment: Two sources:  ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glpk/, instruction:http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Windows. Another: winglpk, http://sourceforge.net/projects/winglpk/files/winglpk/, which doesn't need compile. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the same link problem when you try to link with the precompiled lib from sourceforge?

Comment: I have the same problem when using precompiled lib. And I really use _cdecl(/Gd)

Comment: I don't understand. You accepted my answser? Problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Additional library directory" is not the right way to add a lib file to the link.

Either,

Add glpk_4_52.lib in Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

or

Make the glpk project a dependency of your EXE project, if they are in the same solution, bu using "Project Dependencies" and make sure that Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Link library dependencies is set to Yes

I am able to reproduce your problem by using the H and LIB version 4_52 from the precompiled package on SourceForge, by forcing the calling convention of my EXE to __stdcall (/Gz) (In C++->Adanced).

You should use **__cdecl (/Gd)** instead!

Comment: Yes, even if I add it in the "Additional Dependencies", the same problem is still there.